# Responsive Layout with a Fixed Width Child Element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to implement the following responsive layout in a webpage (HTML5 & CSS3):

[image: Layout]

All three div tags are wrapped inside a div with max-width of 960px;

I want to keep the width of "Navigation" div fixed therefore the following styles are being applied on it:

```
width:90px; float:left; padding:5px;
```

How can I make the "Contents" div occupy all remaining space without specifying its width, while keeping the layout responsive at the same time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#content{
    margin: 0 0 0 90px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put everything in a wrapper div and specify it's width to 960px

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser support you want (need), with only 3 DIVs in a IE6+ way is hard (I think it's actually impossible). You're best bet is with the CSS `calc` method on the Content's DIV
`width: calc(100% - 90px);` The CSS `calc` method has IE9+ support so you would need to take that into account, in IE8- you would still need to use percentages.

If you are wondering how to separate the IE9+ code, then simply use `@media` i.e. something like this:

```
    @media all {
        #navigator {
            width: 90px;
        }
        #content {
            width: calc(100% - 90px);
        }
    }
```

`@media` is IE9+ compadible and because IE8- do not can't make heads or tails of it it will not affect them. So it is safe to place the IE9+ code in it.

If you can modify the HTML a bit I would advice the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #h {
            background: #f00;
        }   
        #n {
            background: #0f0;
            width: 90px;
            float: left;
        }   
        #c_container {
            background: #005;
            width: 100%; 
            float: right;
            margin: 0 0 0 -90px;
            padding-left: 90px; 
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #c {
            background: #00f;
            height: 50px;

        }
        #container {
            max-width: 940px;
            margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="h">head</div><div id="c_container"><div id="c">cont</div></div><div id="n">nav</div>
    </div>      
</body>
```

Note how the *content* has a separate container, with is floated one way and the *navigator* is floated the other way, this is to make sure that they are not on the same plane.

the #c_container has a `margin-left: -90px` to bring it to the same row as the navigator and a `padding-left: 90px;` to make sure that #c (the new content DIV) is now visible. The #c_container also has the #c_container DIV. Without it you would need another container DIV so the width would not be affected by the padding, but that is easy enough to add, so I'll leave it up to you.

If you would use another container DIV for the content, then that solution would be IE6+ compatible, while the one I gave you is IE8+ compatible.